# Sending mail of GAE for PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm follow the Google guide try send an email from PHP on GAE [GAE guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Sending_mail), but I got an error:

Message received an invalid option: body

Below is the code:

```
 require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';

    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

    // ...

    $message_body = "...";

    $mail_options = [
        "sender" => "admin@example.com",
        "to" => "user@example.com",
        "subject" => "Your example.com account has been activated.",
        "body" => $message_body
    ];

    try {
        $message = new Message($mail_options);
        $message->send();
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to either specify `textBody` or `htmlBody`, depending on the format of the message you're sending.

```
$mail_options = [
    "sender" => "admin@example.com",
    "to" => "user@example.com",
    "subject" => "Your example.com account has been activated.",
    "textBody" => $message_body
];
```